# Can't create an while infinite loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a loop in PyCharm to force the user to submit only integers to the program.
But so far, I've only got the input in loop.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: you need to cast the input to an int:
`entry = int(input("Insert an integer number: "))`

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: `type(entry) != int` does not behave as you seem to be expecting it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast the `input()`. In case the user provides a non-integer number, `int()` will throw a `ValueError` you you can subsequently handle as below

---

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Insert an integer number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, you must enter an integer.")
        continue
    else:
        print(f"The number is: {num}")
        break
```

Comment: Question on this: `print("The number is: " + num)` gave `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`. I think it should be casted to `str`, use `str.format()` or `print(f"The number is: {num}")` Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `input` always returns a string. What you can do is to try and convert this string into an int, catch the exception raised when this conversion fails, and ask user to try again. For example, like this:

```
x = None
while x is None:
    try:
        x = int(input("Enter Number:"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Oops, this doesn't seem right, try again!")
```

Comment: `while x==None:` --> `while x is None:`

Comment: @AMC, the kind of stuff python gurus just love to point out... like grammar nazis with miTSakes, lol. Anyway, edited, thanks.

Comment: Eh, I'm not a guru, I just think it's worth mentioning. _miTSakes_ Massachusetts Institute of Technology saké?